# Qual é a diferença entre max-width e max-device-width?

Tags: html5, css3, media-queries

A pergunta é exatamente a que está no titulo,referente ao uso dos *media queries* estou com a duvida pois em exemplos de alguns sites eles usam algo como: `@media screen and (max-widht:x)` e em outros `[...](max-device-width)`.

Aproveitando a pergunta como faço pra definir o *media query* na tag link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max-width` é a largura da área de exibição de alvo, por exemplo, o navegador.

`max-device-width` é a largura de toda a área de renderização do dispositivo, ou seja, a tela do dispositivo real.

Copiada de [SO-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747242/what-is-the-difference-between-max-device-width-and-max-width-for-mobile-web)

Faz sentido...