# Problema na formatação do site

Tags: css, formatação

Bom dia,
estou com um problema com o css do meu site ele apenas funciona a partir do Laptop até ao 4K, alguém me sabe dizer o porquê?

```css
 /*Mobile S*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
.content{
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 250%;
margin-right: 35%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
padding-top: 5%;
border-radius:15px;
    height: 320;
}
}

/*Mobile M*/
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 376px) {
.content{
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 128%;
margin-right: 35%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
padding-top: 5%;
border-radius:15px;
    height: 320;
}
}

/*Mobile L*/
@media only screen and (min-width:377px) and (max-width: 426px) {
.content{
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 111%;
margin-right: 35%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
padding-top: 5%;
border-radius:15px;
    height: 320;
}
}

/*Tablet*/
@media only screen and (min-width:427px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.content{
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 53%;
margin-right: 35%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
padding-top: 5%;
border-radius:15px;
    height: 320;
}
}

/*Laptop*/
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 1025px) {
.content{
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 36%;
margin-right: 35%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
padding-top: 5%;
border-radius:15px;
    height: 320;
}
}

/* Laptop L*/
@media only screen and (min-width:1025px) and (max-width: 2559px) {
.content{
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 25%;
margin-right: 35%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
padding-top: 5%;
border-radius:15px;
    height: 320;
}
}

/* 4K*/
@media only screen and (min-width:2560px) {
.content{
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top: 13%;
margin-right: 35%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
padding-top: 5%;
border-radius:15px;
    height: 320;
}
}
```

Comment: Jovem suas regras de media queries parecem estar na ordem errada... tente começar com as regras de 4k e deixar por último as regras de mobile etc... Faça o teste e veja se da certo, se funcionar me fala que te dou uma resposta com mais detalhes

Comment: Antes de postar já tinha feito isso e não resultou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui resolver!! Vou postar o código para quem precisar. No meu caso bastou colocar device na query.

```css
/* 4K*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width:2560px) {
 .content{
 margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 13%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
    padding-top: 5%;
 border-radius:15px;
     height: 320;
}
}

/* Laptop L*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1025px) and (max-device-width: 2559px) {
 .content{
 margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
    padding-top: 5%;
 border-radius:15px;
     height: 320;
}
}

/*Laptop*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1025px) and (min-device-width: 769px){
 .content{
 margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 36%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
    padding-top: 5%;
 border-radius:15px;
     height: 320;
}
}

/*Tablet*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width:427px) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
 .content{
 margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 53%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
    padding-top: 5%;
 border-radius:15px;
     height: 320;
}
}

/*Mobile L*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width:377px) and (max-device-width: 426px) {
 .content{
 margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 111%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
    padding-top: 5%;
 border-radius:15px;
     height: 320;
}
}

/*Mobile M*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width:321px) and (max-device-width: 376px) {
 .content{
 margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 128%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
    padding-top: 5%;
 border-radius:15px;
     height: 320;
}
}

/*Mobile S*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
 .content{
 margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 90%;
    margin-right: 35%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #666666, #333333);
    padding-top: 5%;
 border-radius:15px;
     height: 320;
}
}
```

Comment: Cara por der resolvido, mas cuidado com isso, pq quando vc fala `device` é a largura da tela do dispositivo, não a largura da janela... faça testes para garantir que nada esta buggando... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140997/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-max-width-e-max-device-width